# RMI/Tomcat 6 Memory Leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, rmi

My application uses both RMI and JDBC to talk to a remote system and a database.  While the database issues have been resolved, it turns out that RMI is causing some form of Memory Leak being detected by Tomcat 6 (I have also tried this with Tomcat 7 and we have the same issue).

Basically, when we start the application and the user enters information into the webpage, an RMI call is made to a backend system.  If we stop/start or restart the application, Tomcat Manager now can detect a memory leak.  If we start the application and do NOT make the RMI call, we can start/stop & restart the application all day long without issues.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to prevent RMI calls from causing Memory Leaks in the WebappClassLoader upon reload or stop/start while the webserver is still running?

Comment: what's the message from tomcat? Is it about ThreadLocal?

Comment: No, that's just it - no error message in the logs.  BUT, Tomcat Manager claims that a leak was discovered if I click on the "Find Leaks" button after doing something in the application that uses an RMI call and then reload/stop the application using the Manager.  I can see in jvisualvm that indeed a new WebappClassLoader (context) is created.

Answer (score 0):

> My application uses both RMI and JDBC to talk to a remote system and a database. While the database issues have been resolved, it turns out that RMI is causing some form of Memory Leak being detected by Tomcat 6 ... Does anyone know what needs to be done to prevent RMI calls from causing Memory Leaks in the WebappClassLoader upon reload or stop/start while the webserver is still running?

RMI calls do not cause memory leaks. I have eight Tomcats that interact heavily via RMI, among other things, that have been up for several months without any sign of a leak.

Comment: When I stop/start or reload the application, Tomcat discovers a Memory Leak if I check using the Manager right after that.  I profiled the JVM using jvisualvm and the culprit appears to be sun.rmi.transport.DGCClient that is at the top of the GC Root.

Do you start/stop or reload the application with the webserver running, or do you stop tomcat after a deployment?

Comment: I can reload it once or twice with Tomcat running, then I have to restart Tomcat. But that applies to Tom says that do do RMI as well. You're going to have to provide proper details here. What memory leak? What's your evidence that RMI is involved? What does your RMI code look like?

Comment: I am not at liberty to reveal code per se, but here's why I say we have a Memory Leak. Tomcat Manager claims that a leak was discovered if I click on the "Find Leaks" button after doing something in the application that uses an RMI call and then reload/stop the application using the Manager. I can see in jvisualvm that indeed a new WebappClassLoader (context) is created.

Comment: Of course a new WebAppClassLoader is created. You reloaded the application. And that has nothing to do with RMI. And no code => no answer.

Comment: No need anymore.  It was the DGCClient needing to clean-up resources.  The cleaner finally ran and the container finished closing.

Answer (score 0):

The DGCClient had not cleaned-up any resources related to RMI and needed to wait for the timeout in order to fire.  Since the container had tried to stop, but the RMI resources were hanging around, this produced a Memory Leak according to Tomcat Manager, that cleaned-itself and corrected the Memory Leak condition after the RMI resources were collected by the DGC.